# Module Parse Failed, Unexpected character

Tags: javascript, webpack, gif, loader, babeljs

Trying to load gif image is .scss file.

This is extracted from my scss file.

```
div.quart:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url("./images/yoga_one.gif");
}
```

this is the webpack configuration file.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: './src/index.js',

output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'scripts.min.js'
},

module: {
  rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
  }],

  rules: [{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
    use: ['url-loader', 'file-loder', 'image-webpack-loader'],
    options: {
      limit: 1000000,
      name: "/src/sass/[name].[ext]"
    }
  }],

  rules: [{
    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    exclude: [__dirname + "/node_modules", __dirname + "/dist"],
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      publicPath: '/dist'
    }),
  },

  {
    test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'fonts/',
        publicPath: '../'
      }
    }]
  }]
},

plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'YinYangYoga - Online Classes and Meditation',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      filename: 'index.html',//localhost:8080
      template: 'src/template/main.html'
    }),

    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      test: /\.js($|\?)/i,
      sourceMap: true,
      uglifyOptions: {
          compress: true
      }
    }),

    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
      disable: false,
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]};
```

And lastly this is the error

*ERROR in ./src/sass/images/yoga_one.gif
    Module parse failed: C:\Users\Vektor\Documents\Web_Repos\Project_responsive_one\src\sass\images\yoga_one.gif Unexpected character '�' (1:6)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    (Source code omitted for this binary file)
     @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./src/sass/style.scss 8:46795-46827*

File hierarchy:

```
├───node_modules
├───dist
│   └───fonts
└───src
    ├───sass
    │   └───images
    ├───scripts
    └───template
```

Comment: How did you create your Image? Looks like it's not encoded properly.

Comment: I wasn't the one who created the image, it was downloaded from the internet. it works fine whenever I use any URL from online but won't work in my local directory.

Comment: The question mark character eludes to the fact that the image is not encoded properly in your file system. Check the image properties to see the encoding. Ideally, it will be UTF8